# How do I calculate the area of Bernoulli's Lemniscate?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, area

can anyone help me calculate this area? I have to use double integrals, and the question sounds like this:
"
Calculate the area bounded by the curve $(x^2+y^2)^2=a^2(x^2-y^2)$, where $a$ is a real constant. I have searched online and found that this type of curve is a lemniscate, but I do not know how to convert $x,y$ to polar coordinates.

Could you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You can find more info [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemniscate.html) (in the notation there: $a^2 = 2c^2$) including how to calculate the area. To go to polar coordinates just take $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ in the equation.

Comment: $r^2=a^2\cos(2\theta)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the lemniscate encloses 4 equal subregions, one in each quadrant, you could use

$\displaystyle A=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_0^{a\sqrt{\cos2\theta}}r\; dr d\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=2(\dfrac{1}{2}\int r^2d\theta)=a^2\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos(2\theta)d {\theta}=a^2$$

Comment: I have to calculate the area using double integrals, so if I substitute x=rcosθ and y=rsinθ it will give me the equation r^2=a^2cos(2θ) , but r and θ  go are in what intervals?